# EditText and buttons overlapping in a single row

Tags: android

For date and time picker I added two edittext and two buttons.Below I am posted the xml codes what I tried so far:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_picker"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:onClick="selectDate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:inputType="time" >
    </EditText>  

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_picker"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:onClick="selecttime" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**button_picker.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#0eabe0"
        android:endColor="#0eabe0"
        android:startColor="#0eabe0" />

</shape>
```

My issue is I get the 2 edittext and 2 buttons in the same line.But its `overlapping`.I need to add some space between each and every views.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: can you add add picture ..... i cant see any overlapping in my machine ...it looks ok

Comment: @Tanimreja if you add the button_picker.xml in drawable it overlapping.Anyway I got an answer with the help of user hanish sharma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use margin Left and Right  and give value according to your requirement instead of 5dp in your views

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all go for a relative layout instead of a linear layout, secondly you can use properties of relative layout like

**android:layout_alignParentTop**, to align your first button to the top, then you can make use of properties like

**android:layout_toRightOf** **android:layout_below** etc to define positions of other elements relative to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way any view can `overlap` another view in LinearLayout. It's just that they all are placed one right next to another. Try using margins to add space between views